# Latency when switching between spaces

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, dock, spaces, monterey

I have a m1 MBP 16-inch with macOS Monterey 12.2. When I switch between spaces using three-finger swipes or control-left/right arrow shortcut, there is a slight but really annoying latency. This latency is not present if I switch again when the last movement has not stopped, or if I switch between apps in different spaces using command-tab.

This behavior is not present in a new user account. I have tried resetting Dock (`defaults delete com.apple.dock`) but that has no affects on this behavior. How can I troubleshoot this problem?

Comment: Compare the difference in speed between ctrl/right arrow & ctrl/1 [assuming you have default key commands set up] Do you see the same difference, or is your swipe even slower than the arrow? Ctrl/num should be about twice as fast as ctrl/arrow.

Comment: @Tetsujin ctrl+1 does not have the lag and is twice as fast.

Comment: Probably not ;) So 3-finger swipe is the same speed as Ctrl/arrow? If so, then it's behaving as expected.

Comment: @ Tetsujin I think I find the culprit. When I only have 2 spaces open, there is no lag. But when there is many open (Chrome windows), there is a lag. The lag seems to decrease when I begin exit-fullscreen these windows and eventually disappear. The lag reappears and increases when I continue to open new windows in Chrome in full-screen mode. Is this a bug or a feature?

Comment: I'd probably just blame the known resource-hog that is Chrome for that. Personally, I refuse to use it because of how much drag it has on everything else.

Comment: @Tetsujin It's still weird because the only thing that changes is the number of Chrome windows that are fullscreen - I did not close or open any new ones. I have a feeling that it's not entirely Chrome's fault. Plus, the animation does not have lag when the last one has not settled down (e.g. when I swipe left, there is a lag, but just as it is about to stop moving I swipe right and there isn't a lag.) What alternative would you recommend? Do you use Safari?

Comment: I only ever use Safari - it's supported by Apple, it integrates properly to macOS. I can't ever see any reason to use something made by a company whose entire business model is to harvest user behaviour for advertising, vs one whose only interest is to sell you next year's hardware ;)

Answer (score 5):

I tried the Accent Colour to no avail. The [general consensus](https://superuser.com/a/1720376) for this appears to be ProMotion slowing the animation. In System Settings -> Displays -> Refresh Rate change ProMotion to 60 Hz.

Fixed it for me. It's a shame however because ProMotion will save battery life. Kind of ironic when you read the last point in Apple's PR!

> ProMotion automatically varies the refresh rate to match the motion of a user's onscreen content to help preserve battery life, and makes tasks more fluid and even more responsive

Oddly, App switching with Command-Tab does not present the issue; only the touch pad swipe and Ctrl-Arrow.

Comment: fixed it for me too! thank you so much

Answer (score 1):

Been living (grumpily) with laggy switching between spaces for months and trying to find a solution. Lag was intrusive with 3-fingered swipe and also with Ctrl-Arrow. Stumbled across [this solution](https://makeitallwork.com/fix-slow-jittery-transition-spaces-mac/) this morning: change the Accent Colour in Preferences/General from Multicolour to Graphite. Snappy space-switching has resumed for me!