# Remove delay after switching space

Tags: spaces, ventura

After switching spaces with a keyboard shortcut, sometimes I need to wait before the animation completes before I can switch space again.

Specifically, with 4 spaces, this happens if switching from space 1 or space 4.

For instance, from 1 to 2, I need to wait before the animation completes and we arrive in space 2. Then I can switch again.

But from 2 to 1, or from 2 to 3, I don't. I can press ^-left, then immediately ^-right and the animation changes course immediately.

Is this just a bug, or is there some way to fix this?

(Not the same issue as [Latency when switching between spaces](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/438188/latency-when-switching-between-spaces) which is a delay before the switch even begins.)

Comment: Never noticed before. I usually use ctrl/[num] not arrows, but I can confirm this behaviour back to Mojave when using arrows.